# How do I increment the moment in my loop to be added to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

```
for (let index = 0; index < $(".hour").length; index++) {
  console.log("test");
  var hour = moment().hour(9).format("h");
  $(".row").find(`[data-hour]`).text(hour);
}
```

This posts 9 in my first div. I would like my next dive to post 10 etc...
I can't figure out how to increment my moment.

image linked of what it looks like in browser

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

```
for (let index = 0; index < $(".hour").length; index++) {
  console.log("test");
  var hour = moment().hour(index).format("h");
  $(".row").find(`[data-hour]`).text(hour);
}
```

**Option 2:** *(Probably more performant)*

```
let myMoment = moment();
for (let index = 0; index < $(".hour").length; index++) {
  console.log("test");
  var hour = myMoment.hour(index).format("h");
  myMoment.add(1, 'h');
  $(".row").find(`[data-hour]`).text(hour);
}
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/